# Entropy for random variable and probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$ be a finite probability space. Then one can
> define the entropy of probability distribution $\mathbb{P}:\Omega\to
>  [0,1]$ as follows: $$H(\mathbb{P})=\sum \limits_{\omega \in
>  \Omega}\mathbb{P}[\omega]\log _2\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}[\omega]} \quad
>  \quad \quad (1)$$
>
> If $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ is a random with a range $S$, then its
> entropy can be defined as follows: $$H(X)=\sum \limits_{x\in
>  S}\mathbb{P}[X=x]\log_{2}\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}[X=x]} \quad \quad \quad
>  (2)$$

Since probability distribution $\mathbb{P}
$ is also random variable, then equalities $(2)$ and $(1)$ should be equal.

Consider the probability space $(\Omega,\mathbb{P})$, where $\Omega=\{\omega_i\}_{i=1}^5$ and $\mathbb{P}[\omega_1]=\mathbb{P}[\omega_2]=\frac{1}{4}$, $\mathbb{P}[\omega_3]=\mathbb{P}[\omega_4]=\mathbb{P}[\omega_5]=\frac{1}{6}$.

The first definition implies that $H(\mathbb{P})=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{5}\mathbb{P}[\omega_i]\log_2\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}[\omega_i]}=1+\log_2\sqrt{6}$

But if we use the second definition with $S=\{\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{6}\}$, we obtain $$H(\mathbb{P})=\sum \limits_{x\in S}\mathbb{P}[\mathbb{P}=x]\log_2\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}[\mathbb{P}=x]}=1.$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you haven't normalized the distribution of the RV, so you are using a conditional distribution

Comment: Why should (1) and (2) be equal in cases where $X$ is not a $1-1$ function?

Comment: @Henry, so are they different definitions of the entropy?

Comment: @kodlu, what do you mean by normalization of the random variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR -- Your first computation is for the entropy of a discrete probability distribution on $\Omega$, and your second computation is for the entropy of a **non-invertible** random variable defined on $\Omega$. If the r.v. were invertible, then these entropies would necessarily be the same; but they are not generally the same in the non-invertible case.

Your r.v. can be described as $X=p(I)$, where $p()$ is the probability mass function of a discrete probability measure $P,$ and $I$ is the identity r.v.  $I:\Omega\to\Omega:\omega\mapsto\omega,\,$ so
$$\begin{align}H(X)&=-\sum_{x\in X(\Omega)}p_X(x)\log_2 p_X(x)\\[1ex]
&=-\sum_{x\in p(I(\Omega))}P\{\omega:p(I(\omega))=x\}\log_2 P\{\omega:p(I(\omega))=x\}\\[1ex]
&=-\sum_{x\in p(\Omega)}P\{\omega:p(\omega)=x\}\log_2 P\{\omega:p(\omega)=x\}\\[1ex]
&=-\sum_{x\in p(\Omega)}\left(\left(\sum_{\omega:p(\omega)=x}p(\omega)\right)\log_2 \left(\sum_{\omega:p(\omega)=x}p(\omega)\right)\right)\\[1ex]
\end{align}$$
and this won't generally reduce to $-\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}p(\omega)\log_2 p(\omega)=H(P)$ unless $\{\omega:p(\omega)=x\}$ is just a singleton, i.e. unless for each $x$ there is only one $\omega$ such that $p(\omega)=x$.

---

**Remarks on the definitions**

The general context here is a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ where $\Omega$ is finite, $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-field subsets of $\Omega$, and the probability measure $P$ is specified by some probability mass function $p()$. (To avoid confusion, I won't use your symbol $\mathbb P$.)

Now, the entropy of such a distribution is defined as
$$H(P):=-\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}p(\omega)\log_2 p(\omega)\tag{1}$$
and if $X:\Omega\to\mathcal X$ is a r.v., then the entropy of $X$ is defined to be the entropy of its distribution:
$$H(P_X):=-\sum_{x\in X(\Omega)}p_X(x)\log_2 p_X(x)\tag{2}$$
where $p_X()$ is the probability mass function of $X.$

**NB**: Using (2), $H(P)$ can also be seen as the entropy of the *identity* r.v. $I:\Omega\to\Omega:\omega\mapsto\omega\,$:
$$H(P_I)=-\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}p_I(\omega)\log_2 p_I(\omega)=H(P).$$

Comment: What do you mean by "TLDR"?

Comment: @ZFR Internet slang for "too long; didn't read".

Comment: Thank you! But I am really confused with the notion of entropy and don't know which answer is correct. Can you take a look please?

Comment: @ZFR I've added some remarks on the definitions, which might help. Note that **the entropy of a r.v. is just the entropy of its probability distribution**. So you can think of your first entropy as the entropy of the identity r.v. $I$ on $\Omega$, and the second one as the entropy of $X=p(I)$. Since $I$ and $p(I)$ clearly have different probability distributions -- because $p()$ is not one-to-one-- we shouldn't expect them to have the same entropy.

Comment: Thank you for the addendum! Let me read all this.

Comment: Excuse me but I am really confused with that sentence "Your r.v. can be described as $X=p(I)$, where $p()$ is the probability mass function of a discrete probability measure $P,$ and $I$ is the identity r.v.  $I:\Omega\to\Omega:\omega\mapsto\omega,\,$"

Comment: My random variable $X:\Omega\to R$ is defined as $X(\omega):=P(\omega)$. But you wrote it can be described as $X=p(I)$, where $p$ is the probability mass function of $P$. Then $X(\omega)=p(I(\omega))=p(\omega)$. But what is $p(\omega)$? It does not make since $p$ is a probability mass function of $P$ so it is domain should be $\mathbb{R}$ be definition.

Comment: @ZFR You're confusing the measure $P$ with the mass.fn. $p.$ The measure $P$ is defined on *subsets* of $\Omega$ , whereas $p$ is defined on the *elements* of $\Omega$; so $X(\omega)=p(\omega)=p(I(\omega)),$ because $I(\omega)=\omega$ for all $\omega\in\Omega.$ I introduced $I$ so we can speak of both of the entropies that you calculate as being entropies of *random variables* (i.e., of $I$ and $p(I)$). We could dispense with $I$ and just speak of both entropies as being entropies of *probability distributions*, (i.e. of $P$ and $P_X$, with $X:=p$).

Comment: Hmm. Ok so let's take a look at the following situation: $(\Omega,P)$ with $|\Omega|<\infty$ and $P(\omega)=\frac{1}{|\Omega|}$ for each $\omega\in \Omega$. The definition (1) tells us that $H(P)=\log_2|\Omega|$. But if we apply definition (2)  we will get $H(P)=0$ because $p_P(\frac{1}{|\Omega|})=P\{\omega: P(\omega)=\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\}=1$. What is wrong? I am so confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136509/discussion-between-zfr-and-r-e-s).

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is there's less entropy on the range of $\mathbb P$ then the domain of $\mathbb P$ in your example, and that the probability distribution on $S$ is technically different. Your range could be considered a finite probability space $(S, \mathbb Q)$ where
$$\mathbb Q[s] = \mathbb P[\mathbb P=s] $$
So
$$H(\mathbb Q) = \sum_{x \in S} \mathbb Q[x] \log_2 \frac{1}{\mathbb Q[x]} = -2 \left (\frac{1}{2} \right  )(-1) = 1$$
is simply a probability distribution with less entropy. It takes two values equally often, instead of considering every possible $\omega \in \Omega$ it could have come from.

Comment: Yeah definition (2) is for probability distributions in the range created by random variables where you "forget" what the inputs are. Definition (1) is for  the domain where you know all the possible inputs.

Comment: I guess the easiest way to think about it is the two definitions are for different things.  Definition (1) is for $(\Omega, \mathbb P)$ and Definition (2) is for $(S, \mathbb Q)$. 
$$\mathbb Q[s] = \mathbb P(\omega \in \Omega:  P(\omega)=s)$$
$$\mathbb P[\omega] = \mathbb P[\omega] $$
They're two different probability distributions on two different spaces, so it makes sense it is sometimes different, especially if $\mathbb P$ isn't 1-1 or anything.

Comment: If $X(\omega) = \mathbb P(\omega)$
$$H(X) = -\sum_{x \in S} \mathbb P(X=x) \log_2 (\mathbb P(X=x)  $$
$$= -\sum_{x \in S} \mathbb Q_X[s] \log_2 \mathbb Q_X[s] = H[Q_x] $$
But $\mathbb Q_X$ is a different distribution than $\mathbb P$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{Q}_X$?

Comment: Sorry, I went past the edit timer 
$$\mathbb Q_X[s] = \mathbb P[\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega)= s] $$

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say this, but there seems to be a lot of confusion of what probability measures are and what are random variables. Random variables are measurable functions. With what respect is the probability measure measurable?

The main point is, that in your interpretation $X$ is a random variable with range $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ where
$\mathbb P(X=1)=\mathbb P(X=2)=1/4$ and $\mathbb P(X=3)=\mathbb P(X=4)=\mathbb P(X=5)=1/6$. The entropy then is about 2.3, which is the same result as in your version with the measure $\mathbb P$.

So, to be precise, the measure $\mathbb P_X:=\mathbb P\circ X^{-1}$ has the same entropy as the $\mathbb P$ in your measure version.

Comment: I'm sorry, a probability distribution is not a random variable! Not even with finite sample space.
As for your first question, the definitions are similar. You just like in (1) at a probability measure, and in (2) at the probability measure induced by a random variable.

Comment: Please look up the definition of random variable and probability measure again. This is really basic stuff. I don't mean to be arrogant, but your question hints at missing fundamentals. The expression $\mathbb P(\mathbb P=s)$ is really non sensical.